# How to add delay before calling next call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I am trying to make a javascript banner. I have 3 images inside a div with ids #img1, #img2 n #img3.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script> 
    var AnimState = true;
    var AnimTime = 2000;
    var AnimDelay = 3000;
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        $('#image img').hide();
        $('#img3').show();
        Show1();
    });
    function Show1()
    {
        if( AnimState === true )
        {
            $("#img3").fadeOut(AnimTime);
            $("#img1").fadeIn(AnimTime, Show2);
        }
    }
    function Show2()
    {
        if( AnimState === true )
        {
            $("#img1").fadeOut(AnimTime);
            $("#img2").fadeIn(AnimTime, Show3);
        }
    }
    function Show3()
    {
        if( AnimState === true )
        {
            $("#img2").fadeOut(AnimTime);
            $("#img3").fadeIn(AnimTime, Show1);
        }
    }
    $('#btn1').click( function()
    {
       AnimState = !AnimState;
       Show1(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

It works fine. The only thing is that now i want to add the delay after fadein effect but trying diff stuffs i failed. So what can be done to add delay for few mins and then only call next function ie. I want to add delay after `$("#img3").fadeIn(AnimTime)` and after delay only call `Show1()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, try this.  After your animations:

```
$("#img1").fadeOut(AnimTime);
$("#img2").fadeIn(AnimTime);
setTimeout(Show3, 30000); //delays next call for 30 seconds
```

Comment: i have also done my job with same solution. I would like to know if it can be done using jquery delay function or not?

Comment: Sure.  You would just have to use .delay() and then some other method that allows for a callback.  But the above is a simple and elegant solution.  I see no reason to use the delay function when this will work just as well or better.

Answer (score 4):

What I do for this is here in this gist: http://gist.github.com/467030

Essentially it lest you create a completely unrelated array of functions, animations or not... and then execute them one by one at the given interval.

```
// create an array of functions to be executed
// everything in each step would be executed simultaneously
var myFuncs = [
    // Step #1
    function () {
        $("#img1").fadeOut(200);
        doSomething();
        doSomethingElseAtTheSameTime();
    },
    // Step #2
    function () {
        doOtherStuff();
    },
    // Step #3
    function () {
        woohoo();
    }
];

// then, the function in that gist: 
// Simple function queue runner. Just pass me an array of functions and I'll
// execute them one by one at the given interval.
var run_queue = function (funcs, step, speed) {
step = step || 0;
speed = speed || 500;
funcs = funcs || [];

    if (step < funcs.length) {
        // execute function
        funcs[step]();

        // loop it
        setTimeout(function () {
            run_queue(funcs, step + 1);
        }, speed);
    }

    return;
};

// run them.
run_queue(myFuncs, 0, 1000);
```

Obviously, this is simpler than you'd want. But the basic idea works really well. Even using jQuery queue() only works for performing subsequent animations on the same items. These can be completely unrelated function executions.

Comment: obeviously nice and gr8 than my thought... thnx alot... i will be working on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#img3").delay('1000').fadeOut(AnimTime);
```

You have to do a sleep function take a look [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/2438) it's a jQuery plygin

usage:

```
$.sleep(3, function(){alert("I slept for 3 seconds!");});
```

Comment: I have tried it but adding it cause the next statment of $("#img1").fadeIn... run first

Comment: Take a look on the sleep function.. I edited my answer.. hope that's usefull

Answer (score 0):

use `$("#img3").fadeIn(AnimTime).delay('1000')`

`1000` is in milliseconds.

Comment: where to add the call back function Show1

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(MyFunction(), 3000);
```

I would do this to simply pause 3 seconds before executing the MyFunction. Hope this helps...