# JavaScript OR jQuery functions to show a result after 20 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, time, logic

How to run javascript/Jquery functions on user specific time scenario its so simple when i click HTML button the result will be show after 20 sec

```
<script>
function setTime(){
   alert("Ok");
}
</script>

<input type ="button" onclick="setTime()" value="Click">
```

Jquery SetInterval,Delay function i don't know how do i implement this please help me out or helps are definitely appreciated

Comment: Have you done *any* research? A simple Google search gave me http://ajaxian.com/archives/delaying-javascript-execution There are also [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372106/delay-javascripts-function-execution) [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879768/best-way-to-put-delay-after-calling-javascript-functions) [SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301398/how-to-add-delay-before-calling-next-call-back-function-in-jquery).

Comment: when i was search this logic in google i found Jquery delay function but i didn't understand how do i implement this logic with delay

Comment: @Samad: jQuery's `delay` is only for jQuery animations.

Comment: That why i put this Quertion here

Comment: @Rocket: You can use it with other functions/queues too, but `setTimeout` is just simpler. That's also explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Comment: what issue is this Question i don't know @Felix Kling

Comment: Thanx Guys for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` if you want to execute anything after certain delay and use `setInterval` if you want to execute some piece of code after every interval with some delay.

In your case `setTimeout` fits the best. Try this.

```
function setTime(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      alert("Ok");
   }, 20 * 1000);//provide the delay in milliseconds
}
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

> Executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.

For example:

```
function setTime(){
  window.setTimeout(
      function() {
          // Your code here...
      },
      20 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(setTime, 20000);
   function setTime(){ 
      alert("Ok"); 
   }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.

Comment: @Yoshi: Maybe, but it's just my instinct to want to fix "bad" code. :-P

Comment: It was not only "bad" code, it was "not working" code. Strings are evaluated in global scope and `setTime` is not global.

Comment: hehe, I wanted to fix it and saw it's already fixed, thx anyway. I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @FelixKling: I didn't actually realize that. :-P

Comment: @Rocket that may be so. Nonetheless I don't think it's the right thing to do. A comment is enough to point out an error.

Comment: @Yoshi the whole point of being able to edit other people's posts is to fix errors

Comment: @Esailija If there is an error, yes. Though aside from indirect error Felix pointed out, the first edit was because of a subjective dislike for a specific usage of a function. This is what I believe to be an improper edit.

Comment: @aKzenT Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(func, delay);
```

The 1st parameter is the function you want to run, the 2nd is the delay (in milliseconds).

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me @Rocket